# jQuery (on click add textbox value to listbox) not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I already asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476073/add-items-in-listbox-in-view-when-button-is-clicked/21476719?noredirect=1#21476719) but this makes more sense i guess

**What I want to achieve**

I want to have a form where user can have upto three textboxes, User will have at least 1 textbox where he can fill in email. Second text box will be shown, if he is connected to a service called superoffice. Third textbox will be shown if he has some contacts in his addressbook.

If there are second and or third textboxes, user will type some text and autocomplete box will be shown based upon result.

Each textbox will have a button next to it called Add when the button is clicked i want the value of the textbox to be added to the listbox on the client side.

When the user submits the form, I want to retrieve all the values from listbox (which is list of email addresses in the form of string).

**What I have done**

This is what I have done till now.

```
public class CreateAppointmentSelectPersons
{

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CreateAppointment_Email_Invalid_Email_Address")]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "RegisterViewModel_EmailId_Email_Id")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsSuperOfficeConnected { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (Resource), Name = "CreateAppointmentSelectPersons_SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_SuperOffice_Contact")]
    public string SelectedSuperOfficeEmail { get; set; }



    public Boolean IsInternalAddressBookEmpty { get; set; }
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "CreateAppointmentSelectPersons_InternalAddressBookPersons_AddressBook_Contact")]
    public string SelectedAddressBookPerson { get; set; }


    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (Resource), Name = "CreateAppointmentSelectPersons_AttendeesListBox_Invited_Persons")]
    [Required]
    public List<string> AttendeesListBox { get;set; }
}
```

and in the view side

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@model DatePicker.Models.ViewModels.Appointment.CreateAppointmentSelectPersons
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","Appointment", new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-8 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" }) <input type='button' id="btnEmail" class="btn-default form-inline" value="Add>>" />
        </div>

        @if (Model.IsSuperOfficeConnected)
        {
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail, new {@class="col-md-8 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-8">

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail,new{@class="form-control",PlaceHolder="Search in SuperOffice..."}) <input type='button' id="btnSuperOffice" class="btn-default" value="Add>>">
        </div>

        }
        @if (Model.IsInternalAddressBookEmpty)
        {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson, new { @class = "col-md-8 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson,new{@class="form-control",PlaceHolder="Search in AddressBook..."}) <input type='button' id ="btnAddressBook" class="btn-default" value="Add>>">
        </div>
        }
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AttendeesListBox, new SelectList(Model.AttendeesListBox), new { style = "width:100%;" })
    </div>
}

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                autocomplete({
                    source: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
                    minLength: 1,  
                    });   
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#SelectedAddressBookPerson").autocomplete({
                source: '/Appointment/AddressBookPerson',
                minLength: 1,
            });
        });
        $(function() {
            $('#btnEmail').click(function(e) {
                var name = $('#Email').val();
                $('#AttendeesListBox').append($("<option></option>").attr("value"), name).text(name);
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#btnSuperOffice').click(function (e) {
                var name = $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail').val();
                $('#AttendeesListBox').append($("<option></option>").attr("value"), name).text(name);
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#btnEmail').click(function (e) {
                var name = $('#SelectedAddressBookPerson').val();
                $('#AttendeesListBox').append($("<option></option>").attr("value"), name).text(name);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller

```
    public JsonResult SuperOfficePerson(string term)
    {
        var persons = _connectionRepository.FindPersonsFromSuperOffice(term);
        return Json(persons.Select(p => new { label = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName, value = p.Email}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    public JsonResult AddressBookPerson(string term)
    {
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var addressBookId = _addressBookReposiory.GetAddressBookId(userName);
        var persons = _addressBookReposiory.SearchAddressBookPersons(term, addressBookId);
        return Json(persons.Select(p => new {label = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName, value = p.Email}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Problem**

The only thing that is working right now is autocomplete 
And the appending to listbox thing doesnot work. Can anyone review and suggest something?

**Rendered Html in broswer**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/docs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/pygments-manni.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.1.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Date Picker</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="9tISS1WGgT7A_GcKUS_Bezvd0y7y2K3Y6tzCcqAfTq6SwnYtmQpTxOMTP59u1ojfg5d9ReUBShCXO1caH8h16QsremZxV7qyDEvW7EjRKb3K2sHxBn0gS7dKEupjCS4rA6SbQat6xJYVde69lBQf3A2" />    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">Hello testaccount!</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="bs-sidebar hidden-print affix" role="complementary">
                    <ul class="nav bs-sidenav">                       
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="/AddressBook">Address Book</a>
                            <ul class="nav">                              
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/AddressBook/AddPerson">Add Contact</a>
                                </li>                               
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Appointment/Create">Appointment</a>                           
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Connection">SuperOffice</a>                       
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    <div class="container body-content">

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<h2>Create</h2>
<form action="/Appointment/Create?class=form-horizontal&amp;role=form" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="eEHQKR1V0OPt21j2EV_SeQVM7yhr7sWgHTEaXGpyroBDoJGSwc-rNm_V75iOTVNns5u5EFjXd__UhwcgnANfXWhF8Tc3n-1UgkdEiYCHYBWtSsXkNItP98neZzgKTz9KwBBdOBvws6I_1eRGvSObTw2" />    <hr />
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>    <div class="form-group">

        <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="Email">Email Id</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email Id field is not a valid e-mail address." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" /> <input type='button' id="btnEmail" class="btn-default form-inline" value="Add>>" />
        </div>

<label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="SelectedSuperOfficeEmail">SuperOffice Contact</label>        <div class="col-md-8">

            <input PlaceHolder="Search in SuperOffice..." class="form-control" id="SelectedSuperOfficeEmail" name="SelectedSuperOfficeEmail" type="text" value="" /> <input type='button' id="btnSuperOffice" class="btn-default" value="Add>>">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="SelectedAddressBookPerson">AddressBook Contact</label>        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input PlaceHolder="Search in AddressBook..." class="form-control" id="SelectedAddressBookPerson" name="SelectedAddressBookPerson" type="text" value="" /> <input type='button' id ="btnAddressBook" class="btn-default" value="Add>>">
        </div>
        <select data-val="true" data-val-required="The Invited Persons field is required." id="AttendeesListBox" multiple="multiple" name="AttendeesListBox" style="width:100%;"></select>
    </div>
</form>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2014 - InfoBridge</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                autocomplete({
                    source: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
                    minLength: 1,  
                    });   
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#SelectedAddressBookPerson").autocomplete({
                source: '/Appointment/AddressBookPerson',
                minLength: 1,
            });
        });
        $(function() {
            $('#btnEmail').click(function(e) {
                var name = $('#Email').val();
                $('#AttendeesListBox').append($("<option></option>").attr("value"), name).text(name);
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#btnSuperOffice').click(function (e) {
                var name = $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail').val();
                $('#AttendeesListBox').append($("<option></option>").attr("value"), name).text(name);
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#btnEmail').click(function (e) {
                var name = $('#SelectedAddressBookPerson').val();
                $('#AttendeesListBox').append($("<option></option>").attr("value"), name).text(name);
            });
        });
    </script>


<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"9bcec3a2cd574a0ea593cf0c8113f386"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4557/068bc91c7f3d4135af92f62145f0c9e6/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

my jquery code was wrong,

```
  $(function() {
                $('#btnEmail').click(function(e) {
                    var name = $('#Email').val();
                    $('#AttendeesListBox').append($('<option value="'+ name +'">'+name+'</option>'));
                });

            });

            $('#btnSuperOffice').click(function (e) {
                var name = $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail').val();
                $('#AttendeesListBox').append($('<option value="'+name+'">'+name+'</option>'));
            });

           $('#btnEmail').click(function (e) {
                var name = $('#SelectedAddressBookPerson').val();
                $('#AttendeesListBox').append($('<option value="'+name+'">'+name+'</option>'));
            });
        });
```

This worked